# How to express psychological insecurity (not physical insecurity)?

Tags: translation, mandarin, cantonese

These two dictionaries seem to offer translations for `insecurity` that capture the physical sort, not the psychological sort (i.e., insecurity about your looks, weight, smarts, etc.).

http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/scripts/wordsearch.php?level=0

https://www.yellowbridge.com/chinese/dictionary.php

Example sentence: What you react to, and what you're sensitive to, often reveal your insecurities.

1) In Mandarin, what's the best translation for psychological `insecurity`?

2) What's the best translation for Cantonese?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Insecurity comes from uncertainty and makes people feel worried and unsafe.

There are so many ways to say insecurity. Here are a few of them.

> 不安
>
> 不安心
>
> 不心安
>
> 心感不安
>
> 心有不安
>
> 惶恐不安
>
> 局促不安
>
> 不妥
>
> 不妥當
>
> 不實在
>
> 不踏實

In Cantonese, Initiate 不 becomes 唔. For example, `不安心` usually becomes `唔安心`. So as `唔妥`, `唔踏實`.

When it comes to "insecurity about your looks, weight, smarts", it could be `無自信`, `無信心`. For example, 對自己容貌無信心.

It is more common to specify this kind of insecurity. For example, in Cantonese, `驚畀人笑` (worry about being laughed) , `驚做唔到` (worry about incapable to do), `驚出醜` (worry about performing in a bad way). `驚` and `怕` is very common word to describe insecurity. It is anxiety about something go wrong.

Some literally translate English phrases like "sense of security" as `安全感` and "sense of insecurity" as `不安感`.

Answer (score 3):

Security (think: Otis Redding) is **安全感**, a very popular and common concept in Chinese.

——

*Oxford* gives the example:

> 有安全感
>   have a sense of security

——

Insecure is **没有安全感**.

*Oxford* has the example sentence:

> 她没有安全感。
>   She feels insecure.

I think Cantonese would opt for 缺乏 over 没有 giving you something like:

> 缺乏安全感